# Obtaining mean from multiple dataframes and inserting result into new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently using Python-3 on juptyer notebook with pandas and have had a tricky time finding the solution to what is probably a simple question (beginner problems!). I have multiple dataframes with identical column headers, and am looking to obtain the mean value of two columns (Col1 and Col2) in each data frame, then inserting the results into two new columns on a new "summary" dataframe (dfSummary).

What I have so far:

```
#find the average of Col1 and Col2 for each of the dataframes and display them in a chart

dfSummary=pandas.DataFrame({"Dataframe_Name":['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6']})

dfList=[dfName1, dfName2, dfName3, dfName4, dfName5, dfName6]
for df in dfList:
    dfSummary['Col1_Mean']=df['Col1'].mean()
    dfSummary['Col2_Mean']=df['Col2'].mean()
print(dfCocktailEff)
```

When I run this, I get something like this:

```
   Dataframe_Name  Col1_Mean  Col2_Mean
0           Name1       21.5       42.4
1           Name2       21.5       42.4
2           Name3       21.5       42.4
3           Name4       21.5       42.4
4           Name5       21.5       42.4
5           Name6       21.5       42.4
```

It looks the way I would like it to, but in each row, it is displaying the mean results for Col1 and Col2 for dfName6 only. I am looking for the mean of the two columns in each dataframe in dfList to be displayed in its corresponding row.

I basically want the for loop to calculate the mean for the two columns and then insert the answer into its respective row and column, then repeat for the other dataframes. I'm not totally sure how to edit my for loop to do this properly though. I've included what I want it to display below:

```
   Dataframe_Name  Col1_Mean  Col2_Mean
0           Name1       20.3       41.3
1           Name2       22.1       42.1
2           Name3       21.1       42.8
3           Name4       22.0       43.1
4           Name5       21.8       41.9
5           Name6       21.5       42.4
```

Where mean of Col1 in dfName1=20.3, mean of Col2 in dfName1=41.3, etc... Hopefully I've explained it well enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, pandas provides ways to aggregate your data without having to construct for-loops. (If you do need to work with individual rows, pd.DataFrame().iterrows() is a series generator,)

The approach is to combine the data, groupby their name, then calculate each mean.

First, let's create some data to work with...

```
name1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,0]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
name2 = name1 * 2
name3 = name1 + 3

name1['Name'] = 'name1'
name2['Name'] = 'name2'
name3['Name'] = 'name3'

df = pd.concat([name1, name2, name3])
```

now we use pandas aggregation

```
df.groupby('Name').mean()

       col1  col2
Name             
name1     5     4
name2    10     8
name3     8     7
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I could replace the for loop with this instead. I did some re-structuring of my dataframes and was able to apply your answer to get the result I wanted. Appreciate it!